# Hide organizational items option in Tridion 2011 SP1 CM snap-in

Tags: tridion

I'd like to limit what organizational items users can actually see in the CM rather than the default which allows them to see the item but not read its contents giving the "Insufficient permissions" error.

For a particular group, I've assigned the Category Management right on a publication and Read permission on only two of forty available categories. When I test logging in as a user of this group - all appears, well:

1. I see only publication the group has the right on.
2. I see all forty categories under Categories & Keywords but
   can only read from the two I set the permission on.

So far so good.

I then opened the Tridion CM snap-in and changed the value "**Hide organizational items if no access to content**" from 0 to 1. Shutdown COM+ and restarted IIS.

Logging in as the same use as before I still see all forty categories as before - there doesn't seem to be any change?

Is it not possible to setup the CM so that my user only see the two categories they have the Read permission on?

Ideally I'd like the same thing for Audience Manager address books too - only listing address books a group has permissions to read/write/delete from.

This is Tridion 2011 SP1.

**EDIT**

Just checked the online docs and they refer to the snap-in setting as:

> If enabled, Folders and Structure Groups for which a user does not
>   have read permission are hidden from that user; defaults to the value
>   0, that is, disabled.

Does that mean it doesn't apply to Categories/Address Books then?

Cheers

Comment: I think you're right, Categories are different from Folders/Structure Groups even though they're still OrganizationalItems.

Comment: Cheers Nuno. Is this something that could be done as a GUI extension maybe?

Comment: Likely - everything seems to be possible - but not necessarily simple. Are you sure about the requirement though? What if the editor needs to create a component that uses a schema that uses a category that the editor has no access to?

Comment: Yeah - the users in question administer contacts in address books and only need to assign a specific keyword to a contact, they don't create content. Perhaps a custom page might be better ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. This setting applies to structure groups and folders.

The term "organizational item" always needs some context to be understood accurately. Categories are, in principle, organizational items, but a category is always a root orgitem, and root orgitems have special rules. In some contexts, even publications are referred to as orgitems. In this specific context, it means folders and structure groups

Comment: Do these special rules mean that the expected functionality can't be achieved via a GUI extension? Haven't looked at Anguilla yet so not even sure if you can extend the navigation pane & list view in this way.

Comment: These rules are implemented in the server, not the GUI. If information is available to the GUI, an extension can hide it, but not the other way round :-)

Comment: Was the Categories root item always visible? I swear not being able to see it with users that lacked Category Management rights in R5.3. Anyone have R5.3 or 2009 to confirm?

Comment: When a category is added, permissions are automatically added for the user that creates the category. You need to manually add permissions for other users/groups